# Don't understand "Object required" error

Tags: xml, asp-classic, parent-child, parent

I have the following ASP classic function:

```
function get_children(n)
  dim local_array
  dim parent
  dim path
  if n.hasChildNodes() then
    for each child in n.childNodes
      local_array = array_merge(local_array, get_children(child))
    next
  else
    set parent = n.parentNode
    while isobject(parent)
      path = parent.nodeName & "/" & path
      set parent = parent.parentNode
    wend
    path = path & "/" & get_attr(n, "file")
    set_attr n, "path", path
    local_array = Array(0)
    set local_array(0) = n
  end if
  get_children = local_array
end function
```

Running this over an XML node (coming from a Microsoft.XMLDOM object), I get the error `Object required: 'parent'` on the line

```
path = parent.nodeName & "/" & path
```

and I can't understand why.  I'm checking `isobject`.  Can anyone explain what the runtime is complaining about, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there is no more parent nodes, you will get a null value back, i.e. `Nothing`. However, `Nothing` is the "null object", so it's also an object. The value of `IsObject(Nothing)` is `True`.

Check for `Nothing` instead of checking if the variable contains an object:

```
while not (parent is Nothing)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but maybe you should use something with/instead if `IsObject`? I suggest to try `IsEmpty()`, `IsNull()` or `Is Nothing`. The latter is used like this:

```
If Not (myObject Is Nothing)
```